# Does IE raise Idle Event to ActiveX in it? If any, how to register my own code to the idle event

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, activex, python-idle

I developed an activex for IE using Delphi 2007 for win32. My question is: How can I get an idle event like getting one from the message loop of TApplication?

I can use a timer of course, but if IE has one, why not use it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: something like TApplication.Idle?

Comment: It sounds like you want IE to notify the ActiveX control when it is done with its processing.  I added a property (bBusy) to my ActiveX control that IE uses to notify the ActiveX control about its status.  In the ActiveX control you can implement a setter for bBusy to test the value and do additional processing when IE changes the status.

Comment: That's not what I want. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such event exposed by IE.